# Using AOS (animate on scroll) inside a div with overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css, animate-on-scroll

I'd really like some things to animate onto screen when I scroll down to them, as they do here...

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

The problem is my site is actually nested inside a div called 'main-content' with seperate divs for the side bar and top bar.

It would appear from [this question and answer](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/issues/15) that its not possible to achieve what I want inside a nested scroller, but this was 3 years ago and I'm just wondering if there is a potential workaround using aos or wow.js or something similar.

I've tried a couple and had no luck but I feel like there must be a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These libraries animate when the window is scrolled and uses information about the window scroll position to animate. There is a possible work-around that you could use. If you placed the content you want to scroll in an iframe, you could place that iframe in your nested div.

Comment: :( Thats the answer I was hoping I wouldn't get. I wonder if theres potentially a way of setting it from window to the div, or maybe it doesn't work like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) makes this kid of behavior easy to implement yourself using vanilla JavaScript. It's a [fairly new API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver) but there's a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill).

If you wanted to track your own scroll container instead of the document you can set the `root` to something else.

```js
// Find the item we want to animate on scroll
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
var targetActiveClass = 'target-is-active';

// Call this function when it enters/leaves the viewport
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add(targetActiveClass);
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove(targetActiveClass);
    }
  });
};

// Create our observer
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {threshold: 0});
observer.observe(target);
```

```css
/* Our target, hidden by default */

#target {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 150vh;
  margin-top: 150vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out,
              transform .25s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
}

/* Apply this class when #target enters/leaves the viewport */

#target.target-is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll!</p>
<div id="target">Howdy!</div>
```